# How do I localStorage a GET Request from an external API Service?

Tags: javascript, request, fetch-api

I have a chain of HTTP Requests (I'm using async await fetch) from a database that is on a server (service API), first, I POST an Authenticate User, then I GET some info from the database. Can I save the data that I GET - locally, so I don't send the HTTP GET Request every time I refresh the browser, the "pending" data takes a while, it can be frustrating.
Here's a piece of code:

```
async function getAssortList() {
 const response = await fetch(assortUrl);
 const data = await response.json();
 const { Assortments } = data;
 console.log(Assortments); // I want to store this data locally
}
getAssortList();
```

Comment: How big can the data be? Local storage has a 5mb cap, so if it can be bigger than that you should be taking a look at using a`cache` in your backend.

Comment: The problem is - I don't have any control on the backend.
Data is pretty big, can be 100k lines of JSON.

Comment: Without a file download, you're out of luck then. If the user is loading a large payload of data you can improve the UX and add messages to the spinner like *We're still processing your request*, *hang tight, almost there...* and let me know it hasn't crashed.